# In which year, people found that sun is not the only star in the universe?

Tags: astronomy

It is a well-known fact now that the sun is one of the multiple stars in the universe.

But in which year people at least hypothesized the fact that we are living in a universe with *multiple stars*?

Answer (score 2):

This belief is known as  [cosmic pluralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_pluralism) and was found among the ancient Greek philosophers:

> After Anaximander opened the door to an infinite universe, a strong pluralist stance was adopted by the atomists, notably Leucippus, Democritus, and Epicurus.

Though this was the belief that stars had planets -- that is, were, like the sun, not just points of light but with satellites.